# Resolve Windows environment variables in PHP

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables

I want to write to a file in the windows temp directory. I know that in the command line you can use the environment variable `%TEMP%` to get the right path, however trying to do something like this:

```
file_put_contents("%TEMP%\\myfile.txt");
```

...does not work because the environment variable isn't being resolved. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getenv('TEMP')` or `$_ENV['temp']`

Incidentally, if you're working with temporary files, then you might want to look into the [`tempnam()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) and [`tmpfile()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) functions.

The former will reserve a temporary file name in any directory (although you can have it create a file in the system temporary directory); the latter will actually create a temporary file and return a file handle resource, automatically discarding the temporary file when the handle is closed.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

file_put_contents(getenv('TEMP') .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "myfile.txt");